# Is there a way to port forward a port to alternate between 2 ips

Tags: port

I have a server on a laptop that I move a round.

if I am at my station I have Ethernet IP-address e.g. 192.0.0.1, and when I'm not I have the wifi IP of 192.0.0.99

is there way to make my router to undestand if ip 192.0.0.99 if offline it should forward the port to 192.0.0.1

Comment: This looks like a question that might be answered on SuperUser, but I don't want to migrate low quality.

Comment: tank you I was not sure where to post it but serverfault felt better then su

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's called a load balancer.